# how to export a image to a folder?

Tags: cocoa

Now I want to export a image in my Project to a folder , I think this is with the NSBundle and NSFileManager problem , but I don't know how to do with it ? Thank very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[someImage TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:@"path/to/file.tiff" atomically:NO];
```

will export an NSImage as a tiff file, although your question is a little vague